# Return selected value from select tag without submit button in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have the following HTML code:

```
    <form action="/GetMatch" method="post">
    <select name="FutureMatches" size="5" id="FutureMatchList" style="width: 18%">
        {% for i in range(user_matches|length) %}
        <option value="{{user_matches[i][0]}}}}">{{user_matches[i][1]}} - {{user_matches[i][2]}}</option>
        {%endfor%}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" id="SubmitMatchButton" value="OK"><br>
    </form>
```

Is it possible to get the value of the selected option once the user clicks it, without needing to press the submit button?

Comment: You can't get it in the Flask view function without submitting the form.  You can get it in javascript.

Comment: Thank you. You can write an answer if you want.

Comment: You can write javascript to make the form automatically submit if an option is selected.